# Change my WHERE query depend on what day it is

Tags: php, sql

I wonder if its possible to use my $today in WHERE query.
If $today is Monday, i want my WHERE to be p650Wdat = 1 (1 stands for monday)
And and tuesday will be 2 and so on.

```
$today = date("l");
<?php
$today = date("l");
//Establish connection to database
$host = "randomtext";
$conn = myacc");
$query = " Select * 
from P660F
where p660WDAT = $today
ORDER BY P660PRIO DESC";
?>
```

Comment: you DB connection looks incorrect and your code is unclear. Please rectify it.

Comment: I Didnt want to show my real connection but my connection works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so you want to match Monday to 1 and Tuesday to 2 etc.  Really you should have same values in table as variables for simplicity and clarity butyou can return the day name as an integer like so

```
<?php
$day_name = date("l");
$today = date('N', strtotime($day_name));
echo 'Today name is ' . $day_name .'<br>';
echo 'Today number is ' . $today;
?>
```

Then your query should work

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the where clause:
SQL:

```
WHERE DATENAME(dw, p660WDAT) = $today
```

MySQL:

```
WHERE DAYNAME(p660WDAT)= $today
```

And your function Date(l) will also return day name as Sunday, Monday... instead of 1,2,3...

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. But i cant figure out where it converts monday to a number 1?

Comment: Your code date("l") gives Sunday, Monday... instead of 1,2,.. can you please verify of this.

Comment: @Mato I think what he is saying is that his table column contains numbers but the string contains day names - so if today is monday he wants to sellect all rows where day = 1, if tuesday then where day = 2

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your RDBMS you can use different ways:
 MySQL:

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(p660WDAT)+1 = $today;
```

PostgreSQL:

```
WHERE  EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP p660WDAT) = $today;
```

P.S. Of course, you should think about escaping values and etc. I didn't mention to give cleaner answer.

P.P.S. If I understood you properly, just use **date('w')** to get day of week.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. But i cant figure out where it converts monday to a number 1?

Comment: Your $today = 'monday', yes? Not integer?

Comment: yes my day is 'friday' today, ANd becouse its friday, i want my where wdat to be 5 than,

Comment: Well, in answer of @Suraz you can compare fields as strings: ** WHERE 'monday' = 'monday' without perfomring to integers.

And if you really need only current day of week, it can be done more simple.

Comment: One more thing. Maybe you can just use **date('w')** instead of **date('l')** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$day_name = date("l");
$today = date('N', strtotime($day_name));
echo 'Today name is ' . $day_name .'<br>';
echo 'Today number is ' . $today;


        $today = date("l");
        //Establish connection to database
        $host = "randomtext";
        $conn = myacc");
        $query = " Select * 
        from P660F
        where p660WDAT = $today


  ORDER BY P660PRIO DESC";
?>
```